# AWS Enable EBS Encryption via cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-control-tower

Is there a way to create a cloudformation script which enables EBS encryption by default for all organizations? There is a aws config rule for this what I am looking for a remediation for this config rule. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/controltower/latest/userguide/strongly-recommended-guardrails.html#ebs-enable-encryption

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is currently not possible via CloudFormation. https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/158

Alternatively, you can enforce the policy that only encrypted EBS volumes can be created or attached by adding the following IAM policy statement:

```
{
  "Sid": "DenyAnythingRelatedToUnencryptedVolume",
  "Effect": "Deny",
  "Action": [
    "ec2:*"
  ],
  "Condition": {
    "Bool": {
      "ec2:Encrypted": "false"
    }
  },
  "Resource": "*"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[As of December 2023, you now can configure EBS Block Public Access using CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/12/amazon-ebs-cloudformation-block-public-access-snapshots/), using [`AWS::EC2::SnapshotBlockPublicAccess`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-snapshotblockpublicaccess.html) .

This is not precisely the same as requiring EBS Encryption, but preventing public snapshots is one of the major reasons people want encryption, and this gets a similar result.